# Recursive binary search / C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I've been trying to write a binary search using recursion (a new concept for me) all day in C. I researched quite a lot and came up with this:

```
int binary_search(int *parr, int value, int left, int right){
    int middle = (left+right)/2;
    if(*(parr+middle)==value){
        return 1;
    }
    if(right<left){
        return 0;
    }
    if(*(parr+middle)>value){
        return binary_search(*parr, value, left, middle-1);
    }
    else{
        return binary_search(*parr, value, middle+1, right);
    }
}
```

And this is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[maxbr],n, i, g;
    do{
        printf("\n n=");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while(n>maxbr);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n a[%d]", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    g = binary_search(arr, 5, 0, n-1);
    printf(" %d", g);
}
```

This crashes after I enter n and the array, for some reason. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is `maxbr`? Have you tried using a debugger to catch the crash and see where it happens?

Comment: Do read the warnings and act on them. If they say you are doing something wrong, chances are you do.

Comment: I use #define maxbr 100 (for example) to define the maximum number of elements the array can have.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want:

```
 return binary_search(parr, value, left, middle-1);
```

Without the * in front of parr.  *parr is the first int, parr is the array.

(fix the other one too)

Comment: Thanks, stranger! That fixed it. Have a great day/night!

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try this one out.

I've implemented a recursive binary search without any pointers and made sure to check all the conditions necessary for binary search.

**Focus on how I've calculated the middle element position.**

> **A very important condition in binary search is that the array should be sorted and always left index <= right index.**

Here goes my code...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int binarySearch(int arr[],int x,int l,int m,int r){
    while (l<=r){
        if(arr[m] == x){
            return m+1;
        }
        else if(arr[m] > x){
            return binarySearch(arr,x,l,(l+(m-1))/2,m-1);
        }
        else if(arr[m] < x){
            return binarySearch(arr,x,m+1,((m+1)+r)/2,r);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(){
    int n,m,x;
    printf("Enter number of array elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int l=0,r=n-1;

    if(r>=1){
        int arr[n],i,j;
        int temp=0,swapFlag=0;
        printf("\nInsert %d elements:\n",n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        }
        printf("Insert complete.\n");

        printf("\nYour array looks like:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }

        //Remember binary search only works for sorted arrays.

        //Applying bubble sort to the array
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            swapFlag = 0;
            for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
                if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
                    swapFlag = 1;
                    //Swapping unordered pairs
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
            //Condition to reduce number of passes & comparisons
            if(swapFlag == 0){
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("\n\nAfter sorting the array looks like:\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        }

        printf("\n\nEnter an element that you want to find: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);

        m = (l+r)/2;
        int result = binarySearch(arr,x,l,m,r);

        if(result != -1){
            printf("\nYes! Element %d is found at position %d.",x,result);
        }
        else{
            printf("\nOops! Element %d is not found.",x);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Binary search is not required as array has only 1 element.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:-**

[image]